Issues with margins while using bootstrap 5
I'm new to coding
I created a grid with 12 columns dividing it into 6, 4 and 2 respectively. I added pictures to column 4 and 2.
The problem I've got it when I added a background color to the div class container that covers them all, it's not stretching to the end of the page. There's a part of the page that is blank while the second picture just falls to another line.
I've tried all I can but I just can't get it. I'd appreciate your input
I tried to change the container to lg or XL but that's not working. I gave added a width of 100% but it still didn't work.
I also tried to style the default margin and padding of the body to zero but it's not working as well.

You'll need to post a [mcve]
